# How to compute $ \mathbb{C}[p_1, q_1, p_2, q_2]^{\mathcal{S}_2}$ under $(p_1, q_1) \leftrightarrow (p_2, q_2)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $B_1 := \mathbb{C}[p_1, q_1], B_2 := \mathbb{C}[p_2, q_2]$
, and $(B_1 \otimes B_2)^{\mathcal{S}_2} = \mathbb{C}[p_1, q_1, p_2, q_2]^{\mathcal{S}_2}$.
Here, the action of $\mathcal{S}_2$ is $(p_1, q_1) \leftrightarrow (p_2, q_2)$.

My question is:
*How to compute  $(B_1 \otimes B_2)^{\mathcal{S}_2}$ in this case ? Or, what is a minimal basis ?*

I think, if the group  action is $\mathcal{S}_2 \times \mathcal{S}_2$; 
$p_1 \leftrightarrow p_2$, and $q_1 \leftrightarrow q_2$, then

$\mathbb{C}[p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2]^{\mathcal{S}_2 \times \mathcal{S}_2} \cong \mathbb{C}[p_1 + p_2, p_1p_2, q_1+q_2, q_1q_2]$.

But,  I don't know how to compute $(B_1 \otimes B_2)^{\mathcal{S}_2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ring of invariants is generated by
$$
p_1 + p_2,\ q_1 + q_2,\ (p_1 - p_2)^2,\ (p_1 - p_2)(q_1 - q_2),\ (q_1 - q_2)^2
$$
with a unique (evident) quadratic relation.

Indeed, denote
$$
p = p_1 + p_2,\ q = q_1 + q_2,\ r = p_1 - p_2,\ s = q_1 - q_2.
$$
Then $\mathbb{C}[p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2] = \mathbb{C}[p,q][r,s]$, and the group preserves $p$ and $q$ and acts by negation on $r$ and $s$. Now it is easy to see that the ring of invariants is generated over $\mathbb{C}[p,q]$ by $r^2$, $rs$, and $s^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. 
I now have a clear understanding !